# Подскажите как вывести в админ панели Django имя авторизованного человека

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-model, foreign-key

Мне необходимо добавить поле ForeignKey где будет отображаться имя авторизованного человека, который формирует заявку.
И поле где будут отображаться модераторы которые берут заявку себе

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Пробовал так ничего не выводит

Моя модель

```
class Support(models.Model):

    APPLICATION_STATUS_CHOICES = [
    ('ОК', 'Обрабатывается'),
    ('ПР', 'Принято'),
    ('ОТ', 'Отказ'),
    ]

    TYPE_QUESTION_CHOICES = [
        ("RN","Возврат"),
        ("WC","Гарантийный случай"),
        ("EX","Обмен"),
        ("RP","Ремонт"),
    ]
    header = models.CharField(verbose_name='Заголовок', max_length=100)
    question = models.TextField(verbose_name='Описание вопроса', null=True, blank = True)
    type_question = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=TYPE_QUESTION_CHOICES, default='ОК')
    date_create = models.DateField()
    application_status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices= APPLICATION_STATUS_CHOICES, default='RN')
    date_change_status = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Моя админ панель

```
class SupportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['header', 'question', 'type_question', 'date_create','application_status','date_change_status', 'user']
    list_editable = ['type_question','application_status']


admin.site.register(Support, SupportAdmin)
```

[image: Админ панель]

Answer (score -1):

Создайте метод в классе SupportAdmin

```
 def someVariable(self,obj):
     return obj.user.first_name
```

и пропишите в классе его

```
@admin.register(Support)
class SupportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['header', 'someVariable', 'question', 'type_question', 'date_create','application_status','date_change_status', 'user']
```